# I'm trying to find files with multiple extensions in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Here's what I have so far

```
DIR="/home/username/Pictures/Wallpapers"

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do
    PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.jpg | shuf -n1)
    PIC1="file://"$PIC

    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri $PIC1
    sleep 30;
done
```

The script works, but I can't figure out how to expand it to find other file extensions, like png or gif in addition to jpg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about using find?

```
find $DIR -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif -print
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Note this will find things in subdirectories too, unless something like -maxdepth is used.

Comment: I tried to use that code like this: 
    PIC=$(find $DIR -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif -print | shuf -n1)
And then I echo $PIC, but only blank lines are displayed.

Comment: Did you write the backslash in front of '*'?

Comment: try it without -print as that seems unecessary.  When I test, it does not work with, but does work without.

Comment: I see the problem: `-print` applies only to the last expression (the .gif files). One would have to add parentheses around the expressions or leave away `-print`, which will be done by default.

Comment: `find $DIR -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.gif" -print`
works also

Answer (score 4):

Assuming bash, the simplest *change* would be

```
PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.{jpg,png,gif} | shuf -n1)
```

Here's a sample on my machine

```
$ export DIR=Desktop
$ PIC=$(ls $DIR/*.{jpg,png,gif} | shuf -n1)
$ echo $PIC

Desktop/polar.png
```

I recommend using find for that, instead.

Comment: when I try that code, I get
    ls: cannot access /home/username/Pictures/Wallpapers/*.{jpg,png}: No such file or directory
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is bash.  I included the shebang at the top of the file.

Comment: I'm using bash 4.2.24 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @bbbgscott what does `shopt extglob` say? (or `shopt|grep glob`)

Comment: extglob is on, the rest of the globs are off.

Comment: colour me silly, I've got the same settings. The only thing I can think of, is that `/home/username/Pictures/Wallpapers/` doesn't actually contain any .jpg or .png files...?

Comment: It has both.  I omitted the gif from the code because I don't have any of those, but the script is fully functional for one extension.  I was just hoping to extend it to multiple extensions.

Comment: When I try this, and edit it down to just the ls command, the error is due to **not having any .gif files** but it does generate a list of .jpg and .png  **Question is how to get ls to stop complaining?**

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I'd go with `find`. It it way more robust in most other respects too